# Debug cordova app from Visual Studio 2013 on Android Device throwing Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug my cordova app on an android device from VS 2013 but I get the following errors when I F5:

**Error 1**

```
C:\Project Path\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2  

File: ERROR building one of the platforms
```

**Error 2**

```
C:\Project Path\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2

File: MDAVSCLI
```

These are the only two errors I get and are not very clear what the problem could be.

I have checked all the System Environment Variables for ADT, Java and ANT and they look correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution for this. I moved to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and it worked fine for me.